# Connection problems with app out of my country

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, review

I have developed an app in titanium studio, and all is working fine. At least here in my country (Portugal). When I send my app to review to Apple they are unable to connect to the server that has the information that my app requires.

This is how I connect to the server:

```
function getData() {

    if (Ti.Network.networkType == Ti.Network.NETWORK_NONE) {
        var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
            ok : 'OK'
        });
        dialog.message = 'Check your Internet connection.';
        dialog.title = 'Alert';
        dialog.show();

    } else {
        var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
            onload : function(e) {
            },
            onerror : function(e) {
            },
            timeout : 30000
        });
        client.open("POST", 'http://approteiros.virtualweb.pt/site/ajax.php');
        client.send({
            action : 'my_action'
        });
    }
}
```

What can be the problem if it's working in Portugal but not working in the USA?

My TiApp.xml file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
                <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I have added this to my XML file.

Answer (score 1):

From the US East coast, the ping to your server is about 328ms, to give you a reference point.

1. Apple's recommendation has changed from what used to be their advice to check a connection then make a call.  Now they suggest firing off the call and if it fails, adjust from there.
2. Your server is also not setup for IPv6. Apple began requiring APPS to work on ipv6 only networks in June, and expect them to start testing servers eventually as well.
3. Also expect apple to require HTTPS connections to api servers by the end of 2016.

So, with all that, lets start with #2.  Your snippet shows a non-ssl url, have you added an app transport security exception to your tiapp.xml's `<ios>` section?

A large number of our clients use AWS for their hosting. Even across the US, connecting from one coast to the other may have a different experience than connecting to ones own coast.

In a few of our apps we have added 2 features.

1. Set a base timeout, we default to 10000ms (your 30000ms should be more than adequate though). On each XHR timeout, we increase it by 5000.
2. The second thing we do is adjust the default based upon device reported timezone offset. So, if the server is US based, for the 5 possible timezones for the continental US (add one for daylight savings time) we set a reasonable timeout, 10000, then for all the others, we start at 25000.

Comment: I have Updated my code. Is that was I added what you mean with this question "So, with all that, lets start with #2. Your snippet shows a non-ssl url, have you added an app transport security exception to your tiapp.xml's <ios> section?"?